# Instance variable array containing other instance variables doesn't reflect changes to contained elements

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

I noticed some weird behavior with instance variables in Ruby the other day.  I was trying to add an instance variable array, containing other instance variable "attributes" of the class.  The class is initialized without any parameters, but I still wanted to create this array at initialization.  Here's an example of a (stripped-down) class:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz
  attr_reader :attrs

  def initialize
    @attrs = [@bar, @baz]
  end
end
```

Here's where it gets weird:

```
f = Foo.new     #=><Foo.0x[object_id] @attrs=[nil, nil]>
f.bar = "bar"   #=>"bar"
f.baz = "baz"   #=>"baz"
f.attrs         #=>[nil, nil]
```

At initialization, I can see that `Foo.attrs` is `[nil, nil]`.  But after updating `Foo.bar` and `Foo.baz`, why is `Foo.attrs` still returning `[nil, nil]`?  Why aren't their new values reflected?

I figured this wasn't the best way to do this, and found a way around it, but I'm still curious about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how variables work, here and in virtually every other programming language.

Your array contains the values of `@bar` and `@baz` *at the time the array was created*. It does *not* contain references to the variables themselves. Modifying one does not modify the other.

Effectively you've done this:

```
x = 3;
y = x;
x = 4;
# Why doesn't y equal 4?
```

`y` is not `4` because `x` and `y` share a *value* but are otherwise unrelated. Reassigning `x` to a new value does not modify the value that `y` contains.

If you want this to work, you need to make an accessor that builds the array on-demand, using the current values of your member variables:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz

  def attrs
    [@bar, @baz]
  end
end
```

Comment: You know, for some reason I convinced myself this was some problem unique to instance variables.  Going back and testing with local variables produces the same result.  And now I feel somewhat dumb.

And yes, that is the solution I ended up using!  Thanks.

Comment: Good answer.  It's perhaps worth noting: `x = 3; x.object_id #=> 7; y = x; y.object_id #=> 7; x = 4; x.object_id #=> 9; y.object_id #=> 7`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `puts` and see what happens

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz
  attr_reader :attrs

  def initialize
    @attrs = [@bar, @baz]
    puts "inside initialize"
  end
end
```

Now you can see initialize gets executed when you create an instance of `Foo`

```
f = Foo.new 
#=> inside initialize
#=> #<Foo:0x2bc1bb0 @attrs=[nil, nil]>

f.bar = "bar"   #=>"bar" , "inside initialize" not printed
```

If you do want to get them assigned then create a setter

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz
  attr_reader :attrs

  def initialize
    @attrs = [@bar, @baz]
    puts "inside initialize"
  end

  def bar=(v)
    @bar = v
    @attrs = [@bar,@baz]
  end

  def baz=(v)
    @baz = v
    @attrs = [@bar,@baz]
  end
end

f = Foo.new 
#=> inside initialize
#=> #<Foo:0x2bc1bb0 @attrs=[nil, nil]>

f.bar = "bar"
f.attrs #=> ["bar", nil]

f.baz = "baz"
f.attrs #=> ["bar", "baz"]
```